# Find a single field from a nested Array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array

Here I have a sample Nested Array. I have a problem with writing proper queries on this collection which is deeply nested.

```
{
"productUUID" : "craft001",
"providers": [
{
  "providerUUID": "prov001",
  "orgs": [
    {
      "orgUUID": "org001",
      "location": {
        "buildings": [
          {
            "buildingUUID": "sit001",
            "floors": [
              {
                "floorUUID": "GrndFlr",
                "assets": [ ],
                "agents": [ ],
                "users": [ ]
              },
              {
                "floorUUID": "1stFlr",
                "assets": [ ],
                "agents": [ ],
                "users": [ ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "buildingUUID": "ist001",
            "floors": [ ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "orgUUID": "org002",
      "location": {
        "buildings": [ ]
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "providerUUID": "prov002",
  "orgs": [ ]
}
]
}
```

Question in simple words, "1. Get all `orgUUID`s which fall under `providerUUID: "prov001"`".
Similarly, "2. Get all `floorUUID`s where `"buildingUUID": "sit001"`".

If someone can help me with the 1st ques, I hope I can solve the 2nd ques myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

For some reason, I had to change the data in collection as following.

```
{
"productUUID": "prod001",
"providers": [
{
  "providerUUID": "prov001",
  "orgs": [
    {
      "orgUUID": "org001",
      "floors": [
        { "floorUUID": "SIT_GrndFlr" },
        { "floorUUID": "SIT_1stFlr" }
      ],
      "assets": [{},{}],
      "agents": [{},{}],
      "users": [{},{}]
    },
    {
      "orgUUID": "org002",
      "floors": [
        { "floorUUID": "IST_1stFlr" },
        { "floorUUID": "IST_2ndFlr" }
      ],
      "assets": [{},{}],
      "agents": [{},{}],
      "users": [{},{}]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "providerUUID": "prov002",
  "orgs": [
    {
      "orgUUID": "org001",
      "floors": [{},{}],
      "assets": [{},{}],
      "agents": [{},{}],
      "users": [{},{}]
    },
    {
      "orgUUID": "org002",
      "floors": [{},{}],
      "assets": [{},{}],
      "agents": [{},{}],
      "users": [{},{}]
    }
  ]
}
]
}
```

so, now with the help of @yogesh, I was introduced to `aggregate` and was able to write queries for my questions.

```
1. Get all `orgUUID`s under `providerUUID: "prov001"`.
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$providers"},
                        {"$match":{"providers.providerUUID":"prov001"}},
                        {"$project":{"orgUUID":"$providers.orgs.orgUUID"}},
                        {"$unwind":"$orgUUID"},
                        {"$project":{"_id":0,"orgUUID":1}}
                       )

2. Get all `floorUUID`s under `orgUUID : "org001"`.
db.collectionName.aggregate(
    { "$unwind" : "$providers" },    
    { "$match" : { "providers.providerUUID" : "prov001" } },    
    { "$unwind" : "$providers.orgs" },    
    { "$match" : { "providers.orgs.orgUUID" : "org001" } },    
    { "$project" : { "floorUUID" : "$providers.orgs.floors.floorUUID" } },    
    { "$unwind" : "$floorUUID" },    
    { "$project" : { "_id":0 , "floorUUID" : 1 } }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Mongo [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) use to finding to nested documents. First `unwind` all `providers` array then use `match` to match `providerUUID` as given `prov001` then used `project` to get all `orgUUID` and aggregation query as  :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({"$unwind":"$providers"},
                            {"$match":{"providers.providerUUID":"prov001"}},
                            {"$project":{"orgUUID":"$providers.orgs.orgUUID"}},
                            {"$unwind":"$orgUUID"},
                            {"$project":{"_id":0,"orgUUID":1}}
                           ).pretty()
```

this will returns all `orgUUID` in an array.

If you use [$elemMacth](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) then this operator having it's own limitation as

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

`elemMatch` query as :

```
 db.collectionName.find({"providers":{"$elemMatch":{"providerUUID":"prov001"}}},
                        {"providers.$.providerUUID.orgs.orgUUID":1}).pretty()
```

it returns whole matching `providers` array.

I hope you will find out **"2"** question query yourself, If you having any trouble with finding with **"2"** query I will post **"2"** query also. Try to yourself to find out second query answer yourself :)

Comment: In first aggregation query if you write after `$project` unwinding `orgUUID` like this `$unwind:$orgUUID` you will get your expected result